# Wrong Class format exception when migrating Java6 to Java8

Tags: java, drools

I am using Java8 , drools5.6.1 , Tomcat 8.5 , ecj 4.6.1---

```
  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:329)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.createNameEnvironmentAnswer(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:275)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:246)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.resolve(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(BinaryTypeBinding.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.getExactMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findExactMethod(Scope.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getMethod(Scope.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AllocationExpression.resolveType(AllocationExpression.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.resolveType(Assignment.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:411)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:358)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:368)
    at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:53)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:70)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:844)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:801)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:361)
    at com.rs.sw.promopack.PromopackRuleBaseManager.writerToPackage(PromopackRuleBaseManager.java:488)
    at com.rs.sw.promopack.PromopackRuleBaseManager.createPackage(PromopackRuleBaseManager.java:245)
    at com.rs.sw.promopack.PromopackRuleBaseManager.performModifications(PromopackRuleBaseManager.java:430)
    at com.rs.sw.promopack.PromopackRuleBaseManager.performModifications(PromopackRuleBaseManager.java:396)
    at com.rs.sw.promopack.PromopackRuleBaseManager.getRules(PromopackRuleBaseManager.java:328)
    at com.rs.sw.promopack.RulesBaseManagerTest.assertResults(RulesBaseManagerTest.java:45)
    at com.rs.sw.promopack.RulesBaseManagerTest.testDuplicateAction(RulesBaseManagerTest.java:97)
```

Comment: What's your dialect? If you use mvel dialect, this should work as-is. Java dialect requires some additional configuration I think (you may need to swap out the eclipse jdt compiler ... there's other questions that cover this.)

Comment: Hi Sir can you please explain  ? I have to change eclipse jdt  compiler version. (ecj version)

Comment: So you are using Java dialect in your rules?

Comment: No we are not using .

Comment: Then why are you trying to change your compiler version? Are you doing this in any sort of controller way because at this point it seems like you're just changing things randomly to see if it works.

Comment: We are using .ftl file for Condition. Sample for one file-<#switch (Apply) >
 <#case "BY_CHEAPEST" >
     <@createConsumer valueToApply unitMeasure >
  regComparator.sort($registrations, "cheapestFirst")
        </@createConsumer>
        <#break>
    <#case "SELECTION_AVERAGE" >
     <@createConsumer valueToApply unitMeasure >
  regComparator.sort($registrations, "mostExpensiveFirst")
        </@createConsumer>
     <#break>
 <#default>
  <@createConsumer valueToApply unitMeasure >
         $registrations <#--sorted above -->
        </@createConsumer>
  <#break>
</#switch>

Comment: Well now that you're on a modern version of drools you can swap out those freemarker templates for proper rule templates. :) You should put your solution as an answer instead of a comment so that future users will benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved. I have removed "eclipse.jdt.core" jar and replaced with "ecj" jar and updated project with maven update. I started working .
Thanks Roddy .